# session and cookie not working

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

okay....i'm sending some variables over forms...i tried with borh session and cookie, i'm getting an error :undefine index

sending

```
session_start();
$host="localhost";      // Host name
$username="";           // Mysql username
$password="";           // Mysql password
$db_name="test";        // Database name
$tbl_name="test3";      // Table name
$tbl_name1="scan";      // Table name

$invoiceno = $_GET['invoiceno'];
//$_SESSION['invoice_no']=$invoiceno;

$expire=time()+60*60*24;
setcookie("user1", "$invoiceno", $expire);
```

to this from

```
session_start();
$host="localhost";      // Host name
$username="";           // Mysql username
$password="";           // Mysql password
$db_name="test";        // Database name
$tbl_name="test3";      // Table name
$tbl_name2="scan";
$db_name1="test1";      // Database name
$tbl_name1="test2";     // Table name

$invoiceno=$_COOKIE["user1"];                           // session invoice no. 

echo $_COOKIE["user1"];
```

can someone help me...thank you

Comment: Please post the whole error message and specify in which line it's generated.

Comment: I think you misunderstand session and cookie. If you think about a session then you must use $_SESSION['user1']=$invoiceno; and echo $_SESSION['user1'];
Try this ....

Comment: okay....when i run this code from my pc its working...but currently i'm running it from a handheld and its not working...does wifi affects the session variable?

yes,i'm using get

the error: undefined index:user1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handheld not supporting cookies. Try use cookiless session (not recommended).